# PostgreSQL Select Last 30 Days with Results

Tags: postgresql, select

I'm needing a `PostgreSQL` **last 30 days** report where some of the days might not have entries.  So last Tuesday migth not have any records.  Wednesday might have 8 records.

This is going into a bar chart so every day for the last 30 days is required.  Relying on the database only, is there a way to force a result of the last 30 days, plus corresponding result values, even if nil?  I'd have to set that last one to 0.  Right now I have a result with only 16 days showing up.

I'm thinking I have to iterate the result in `Ruby` to get the data set I'm looking for.  I'm trying to rely on the database instead of running outside for further processing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT creation_date::date as myday, count(id)
FROM queries
GROUP BY myday
ORDER BY myday DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to try to use generate_series to first get a counter from 0 to 29, and use a left outer join, try the following (note, it would be helpful to know what tables you are using):

```
SELECT a."TheDate", COALESCE(b."recs", 0)
FROM
(
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - i "TheDate"
    FROM generate_series(0, 29) i
) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT "TheDate", COUNT(*) "recs"
    FROM "Records"
    WHERE "TheDate" > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 DAY')::DATE
    GROUP BY "TheDate" 
)b ON a."TheDate"=b."TheDate"
```

Comment: Single table **queries**.  So you do create a series then use that as a join.  OK I will study your solution.

Comment: @Rich_F I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "single table queries"

Comment: Queries from a single table.  I edited the initial post.